# Need to specify a config file to PhantomJS-node bridge

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

First of all, I'm using node with the [phantomJS bridge](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node).

PhantomJS is v1.9.2

Node is v0.10.15

My problem is that I can't set a config file to phantomJS-node.

Basically my code goes :

```
var phantom = require("node-phantom");

phantom.create( function ( err, ph ){

    ph.createPage( function ( err, page ){

        page.set( "settings.config", "./myConfig.json" );

        page.get( "settings", function( err, settings ){
            console.log(settings);
        });

    });
});
```

I'm only getting default settings in the `console.log(settings);` :

```
{ XSSAuditingEnabled: false,
  javascriptCanCloseWindows: true,
  javascriptCanOpenWindows: true,
  javascriptEnabled: true,
  loadImages: true,
  localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: false,
  userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.2 Safari/534.34',
  webSecurityEnabled: true }
```

I've tried many things to assign my config's file to phantomJS or my page's instance, with no luck.

`set('settings.config')` on `phantom` or `phant`, but without any result.

I've also tried, as it's said in the doc :

```
phantom.create("--config=./path/to/config.json", function ( err, ph ){
    ...
});
```

Error, need a function as first parameter. So I've tried :

```
phantom.create(function ( err, ph ){
    ...
}, {"--config":"./path/to/config.json"});
```

Still no luck.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT : I wasn't using the right documentation ( -_- ) ...**

So the right way to do it with `node-phantom` (the one I was finally using) is :

```
phantom.create( callback, { parameters : {"config" : "path/to/file.json" }});
```

And I can confirm, it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are not looking the right documentation... There are two main packages for PhantomJS on Node.js :

- *phantom* (https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node)
- *node-phantom* (https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom)

I see that you are using *node-phantom* :

```
var phantom = require("node-phantom");
```

But you are trying to use a *phantom* function. As it is written in *phantom*'s documentation :

> Properties can't be get/set directly, instead use p.get('version', callback) or p.page.set('viewportSize', {width:640,height:480}), etc. Nested objects can be accessed by including dots in keys, such as p.page.set('settings.loadImages', false)

But there doesn't seem to be a literally equivalent function for the package *node-phantom* that you are using.

Hope it helps!

Comment: OMG ! I'm an idiot...

The equivalent for `node-phantom` is :

`phantom.create( callback, { parameters : {"config" : "path/to/file.json" }});`

And I can confirm, it's working now.